# Identify comic book about a human fighting in an alien league with psychic weapons

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this comic circa late 80s to early 90s from a cousin with an extensive and esoteric collection. I don't believe that the comic was DC or Marvel and my memory of the style suggests maybe Image or similar. It was very likely not manga of any sort.

The specific issue I was allowed to read dealt with a fighting league of some sort in a distant galaxy. The combatants fought with psychic weapons. Nearly all of the combatants and all of the winners were aliens since humans were judged unfit for this type of mind-based combat. They were all ranked by 1 through 10 (maybe "One" through "Ten") and only the greatest was a "Ten". There was one human that was good enough to at least battle the very arrogant (maybe multi-armed and red) champion but he ultimately lost. In the end panel of this issue, his hand had been chopped off and the "Ten" champion intended to let him bleed to death.

I've searched for this comic on and off for the past 20+ years with zero luck.